# ignoring duplicate mysql values in php

Tags: php, mysql

Once I run my query, joining several columns together, I get results like this:

```
id     item     category
1      item 1   A
1      item 1   B
1      item 1   C
2      item 2   A
2      item 2   D
3      item 3   B
3      item 3   E
```

I've got a while loop that will output each row:.

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
    echo $results['item'].<br>;
    echo "Category: ".$results['category'];
}
```

and it's giving this:

```
<div>
Item 1
Category: A
</div>

<div>
Item 1
Category: B
</div>
```

and so on, but what I need to do is combine all the values for each ID into one space, so the results look like:

```
<div>
Item 1
Category: A, B, C
</div>

<div>
Item 2
Category: A, D
</div>

<div>
Item 3
Category: B, E
</div>
```

What's the best way to do this? Should I create another array with the rows for each ID, and loop through that (and how would I set up the array?) Or is there something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `GROUP BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: Looks like GROUP_CONCAT is what I need. I tested it on multiple columns, and it seems to be working, but to confirm that - suppose I had two more columns, say, an address and a city, so item 1 would have address1, city1; address2, city2; address3, city3. GROUP_CONCAT would always keep the order the same, returning address1,address2,address3 and city1,city2,city3?

Comment: To follow up a bit more (since my actual data's more complicated than my example), what if item 1 took up nine rows without grouping (three categories, all three addresses for each category)? Grouping them would either give A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C, or with DISTINCT it would give A,B,C, but then I'd lose the association between category and address. Can I concatenate on multiple columns?

Comment: The HTML output I'd want is Category: A (at addr1, city1 or address2, city2, or addr3, city3), B (at addr1, city1 or addr4, city4, or addr5, city5), C (at addr1, city1 or addr2, city2, or addr6, city6). I'm sure some of it will require code on the PHP end, but how can I best preserve the associations while keeping one row per ID?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this all in your query instead of relying on PHP.

```
  Select item, group_concat(category) FROM yourtable GROUP BY Item
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :

```
select id, item, group_concat(category) from Table1
group by id, item
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e49f/2)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of categories for each item:

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
    $items[$results['item']][] = $results['category'];
}
```

Then use that to output your HTML:

```
foreach ($items as $itemName => $categories) {
    echo $itemName.'<br>';
    echo 'Categories: '.implode(', ',$categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the ability to change the query that gets the data from the database you can use the PHP helper function `array_unique`. This function removes duplicate values from an array. While it is better to do this in MySQL, its not always possible for the developer to do this easily so this would help. Here is a link to the PHP manual on this function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php